# Plot data to google-charts with EJS templating

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-visualization, ejs

I'm trying to plot a google-chart with an EJS template.

This is my code until now:

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Price'],

          <% prices.forEach(function(price) { %>
           data.addRows([ <%= price.close %>]);
            <% }); %>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

How can I loop through EJS variable inside the Google chart function so I can plot the chart?

Comment: Also doesn't work

Comment: you need at least two columns of data, also [addRows](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addRows) requires another array